# can i merged 2 (or maybe more) php functions in on php script?

Tags: php

im a begginer.
is it possible to put two functions in one php script?, per example:

having a php script loading a xml file (simplexml_load_file)
and then after I've got the data i want to from that xml also put the DomDocument functions(and  variables and all that) to create another xml and write the data parsed(to just the data i want,or maybe convert the data to json format.
**Question1:is it possible?**
**Question2: or do i need to run those functions in separate scripts with exec();function ?**

any explicit explanation is appreciated or link to learn about it.
-Thanks.

Comment: Guys, do not vote down a beginner. He is trying to understand PHP and that is a constructive thing to do. I believe none of the 3 down-voters has written PHP code since they were dressed in diapers. So, please, people, show some empathy.

Comment: @LajosArpad thanks for the Empathy,colleague !theres a lot of users making points by down voting beginners questions/users(learn something else,improve yourself by educating your soul,not putting down others!, Down Voting is not really fair!,that just shows their "knowledge/wisdom"(PRIDE) !this is a place to LEARN from others NOT to Step On Others.

Comment: Actually, down-votes are helpful if they are paired with a comment, stating why the question/answer is mistaken or not helpful. However, here there were no such comments. Also, your question was perfectly valid. The answer is obvious for us, but it is not so obvious for you, hence the question. Do not feel bad about the down-votes. Your question was not a very good question, but was not a bad question either. The only reason I have up-voted it was to show my support to beginners.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call any number of functions in your one script file.

Answer (score 0):

A php file holds php code. Your php code can contain classes, functions, function calls and so on. You have to focus on the following though:

- Typing: have correct syntax
- Correctness: avoid bugs in your code, test everything
- Separation: a php file should hold closely related code. This is not mandated by the language, but it is common-sense. You will not want to have a file containing conversion functions and date functions, because it is frustrating to read it, so it is beneficial to separate conversion functions from date functions

There is no limitation for function numbers or function call numbers per file for php.

I would suggest that you should watch some nice tutorial movies about php. A good and comfortable way to learn the language. [Example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KL7_wZSTY6Y).

Comment: -Thanks for your Answer @LajosArpad : your answer and NeedhiAgrawal answers are useful to me, all we know thats hard making points here as a beginner stage.

Comment: @Mr.Mol, I am happy we were able to contribute to your learning process. All the best of luck :)